# Is adding new properties to `this` outside `constructor()` method considered bad pratice?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented-analysis

I have the following class:

```
class Sample {
   constructor() {
       ...
       this.extra_method();
   }

   extra_method() {
      this.property1 = "property1";
      ....
   }
}
```

Is it more appropriate to move the properties-adding logic(`this.property1 = "property1";`) into the `constructor()` method?

I am looking for specific reasons, not opinions. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you reword to emphasize that you're looking for specific reasons, not opinions.

Comment: If the property isn't needed initially, and the constructor has no way of knowing what to put in it, how could it initialize it at that time? Do whatever makes most sense for the application, there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer to this question.

Comment: @Barmar - Typically by using `undefined`. And agreed, there is no one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: In particular, an object might use dynamic properties, so it's not possible to know all the properties at construction time (although you could just make that a nested object, rather than putting the properties in the main object itself).

Comment: @Barmar - Perhaps a `Map` even. :-)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript engines aggressively optimize objects, including property lookup on objects, by (amongst other things) making property lookup not a B-tree-style lookup, but something closer to a dispatch table. (V8, the JavaScript engine in Chrome, Node.js, and others compiles machine-code classes for code that's identified as a hot spot in the program; see [this article](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties) for details.) That means every time the *shape* of the object (what properties it has) changes, the engine has to adjust the optimized object to handle that (or de-optimize the object).

Modern engines largely expect that once your constructor has returned, the shape of the object is set and ready to be optimized. That means adding properties to it later can de-optimize the object (turning it into a bit of a B-tree map) or cause the engine to have to re-do its optimization.

Does it matter? It depends on whether the objects created by your class are a performance bottleneck. If so, avoiding shape changes may help. If not, it doesn't matter. So whether it's "best practice" may fall in the realm of opinion.

Comment: So setting `this.property1 = undefined` in the constructor, makes setting `this.property1 = "property1"` later on fine?

Comment: @3limin4t0r - Right, because that just changes the value of the property, not the shape of the object. But again, this only matters in performance-critical code.